# When does Windows start using the page file/disk as RAM?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, memory, pagefile

My system has been slowing down a lot and I was wondering if that is because I only have 2GB of RAM. Would an upgrade to 4GB fix that?

Comment: Depends;  Have you determined if you are running out of system memory?

Comment: No it doesn't depend. 2Gb is not enough for routine use in 2016. On linux maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Windows uses a swap file no matter how much RAM you have even 16+gb.  Windows pages out old data, plus other things.  When you launch an intensive program like a video game it immediately start pushing stuff out of memory to allow the game the most amount of RAM possible.

If an windows crashes, like a blue screen, it dump the contents of RAM to the swap file tile it can transfer it to a memory.dmp file.

Honestly 4gb will be better, but 8gb is a lot better.  Then get an SSD and things should zooom along.

Answer (score 0):

In general 2Gb of RAM is not enough to multitask with modern programs, so if you're multitasking with modern program then, yes, your RAM is slowing you down and upgrading to 4gb would speed up your computer. Once you've done that the next step to speed up your computer is to buy an SSD. Third is to clean your system of malware and don't run an antivirus (windows now has built in and antiviruses are major resource hogs). These are the tree biggest things you can do to speed up an old PC.

Comment: Im probably not upgrading to a SSD since they are not cheap, and my motherboard is only SATAII so it probably woudnt improve peformance a lot. I will disable my anti virus, I will upfrade to 4GB soon.

Comment: An SSD would give you a huge improvement even over SATA II, you can get a small one such as 64 or 128 gb to run your system and use your old drive for storage. The small ones are not expensive.

Comment: With an SSD you should'nt be just looking at the maximum linear read. The seek time is way faster with SSDs and that isn't limited by SATA II.

Comment: huh, ok, ill chek some out

Comment: Intel 320 SSDs are on ebay for 30$ +/-; that is relatively cheap for the speed boost.